# Is this distribution unimodal, even though there is no data on one side of the mode?

Tags: distributions, mode

... or does there need to be data on the left side of the mode? The logic to "not unimodal" would be that there must be a peak to be unimodal and there's no peak if the data only decreases on one side.

[image: is_it_unimodal]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes; it is. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodality
Unimodality requires a unique highest value, even if it is attained at an edge. For example, the exponential distribution is considered unimodal.